# Jquery hover function not working not working on hover out

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a hover function for and eye on a face. When I hover over it works properly(the ee disappears), but when I hover out the visibilityshow class does not display (the eye does not reappear)

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Kow Your Face</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".lefteye").hover(function(){
    $(".lefteye").addClass("visibilityhidden");
    },function(){
    $(".lefteye").addClass("visibilityshow");
  });
});
</script>
</script>

<style>
.visibilityshow {
    visibility: visible;
    }
.visibilityhidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
#face {
    background-image: url(face.png);
    width: 262px;
    height: 262px;
    }
.lefteye {
    background-image: url(circle.png);
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    position: relative;
    top: 69px;
    left: 59px;
    }
.righteye {
    background-image: url(circle.png);
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    position: relative;
    top: 41px;
    left: 167px;
    }
.mouth {
    background-image: url(circle.png);
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    position: relative;
    top: 84px;
    left: 114px;
    }           
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="face">
        <div class="lefteye">
        </div>
        <div class="righteye">
        </div>
        <div class="mouth">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="lefteyedes" style="display:none;">
    <p>Left Eye</p>
    </div>
    <div class="righteyedes" style="display:none;">
    <p>Right Eye</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mouthdes" style="display:none;">
    <p>Mouth</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html
```

>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the class on mouse out, not to add another class

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".lefteye").hover(function(){
    $(".lefteye").addClass("visibilityhidden");
    },function(){
    $(".lefteye").removeClass("visibilityhidden");
  });
});
```

Even simple you can just toggle the class

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".lefteye").hover(function(){
    $(".lefteye").toggleClass("visibilityhidden");       
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably remove the previously added class:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".lefteye").hover(function(){
        $(".lefteye").addClass("visibilityhidden");
        $(".lefteye").removeClass("visibilityshow");
    },function(){
        $(".lefteye").addClass("visibilityshow");
        $(".lefteye").removeClass("visibilityhidden");
      });
});
```